# What is the canonical way to convert a MethodDeclarationSyntax to a ConstructorDeclarationSyntax?

Tags: c#, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm writing an analyzer and codefix for an API migration ([AutoMapper V5 Profiles](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#profiles)), converting a `protected override Configure` method to a constructor:

from:

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    protected override Configure()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
        RecognizePrefix("m_");
    }
}
```

to

```
public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
    public MappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Foo, Bar>();
        RecognizePrefix("m_");
    }
}
```

I've found a way to convert the method node into a constructor, but I've been struggling a lot to get the whitespace right. This begs the question if I'm not overlooking a simpler way of converting a method to constructor.

So my question is: does Roslyn already give you a refactoring to convert a `MethodDeclarationSyntax` to a `ConstructorDeclarationSyntax`? Or an easier way than [this LINQPad script](https://gist.github.com/tiesmaster/4a2a81b83c45dcd336fb5757b1eaab56).

Comment: Can't you just take the body of the method and create a constructor with that as body? Then format the entire constructor and whitespace will be pretty.

Comment: No, since the existing formatting of the method body will be wiped out by `NormalizeWhiteSpace()`, which we want to keep

Comment: @Ties format the constructor with an empty/dummy body first, then add the old body, which is already formatted

Comment: I tried that, but then the indentation level is off: NormalizeWhitespace will put the constructor at indentation level 0...

Comment: Have you tried `.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)` ?

Comment: That's a really good idea, I'll give that a try. I have played around with that previously, but couldn't get it to work in an expected way. Do you have some links to blogs for examples where it is being used?

Comment: In your CodeFix, use `SyntaxFactory.ConstructorDeclaration(constructorIdentifier).WithModifiers(SyntaxFactory.TokenList(SyntaxFactory.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))).WithAttributeLists(oldMethodNode.AttributeLists).WithParameterList(newParameterList).WithBody(newBody).WithTriviaFrom(oldMethodNode).WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation)`. It really should be as simple as that. Note that this may not work outside the CodeFix. Somebody has to process the annotation, and code fixes do that.

Comment: Outside of a CodeFix, you can use `Formatter.Format()` from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting`. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19711218/how-to-add-white-space-and-or-format-code

Comment: Thanks Kris, I'll give that a try, when I'm all better (unfortunately, I'm stuck at the moment :()

Comment: @KrisVandermotten Thanks. I tried the Formatter annotation, and that worked like a charm! I knew it existed, but didn't really understand it, but now I do :) If you convert your comment into an answer, then I'll accept it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a CodeFix, just add the formatter annotation:

```
SyntaxFactory
    .ConstructorDeclaration(constructorIdentifier)
    .‌​WithModifiers(Syntax‌​Factory.TokenList(Sy‌​ntaxFactory.Token(Sy‌​ntaxKind.PublicKeywo‌​rd)))
    .WithAttributeL‌​ists(oldMethodNode.A‌​ttributeLists)
    .WithP‌​arameterList(newPara‌​meterList)
    .WithBody(‌​newBody)
    .WithTriviaF‌​rom(oldMethodNode)
    .W‌​ithAdditionalAnnotat‌​ions(Formatter.Annot‌​ation)
```

That's enough to do the trick in a code fix, because the code fix infrastructure will process the annotation.

Outside of a CodeFix, you can use `Formatter.Format()` from `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Formatting` to process the annotation explicitely.