# Incorrect syntax is generated when creating a UsingDirective from factory in Roslyn

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I am using Roslyn in order to generate a tree from another one. So we are dealing with AST transformation. I am using `SyntaxFactory` in order to generate nodes.

In the specific case I want to create a u `using` directive that should look like this:

```
using MyNamespace.SubNamespace;
```

So I do:

```
var usingDirective = SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(SyntaxFactory.ParseName("MyNamespace.SubNamespace"));
var newNode = mynode.AddUsings(new[] { usingDirective });
```

But if I inspect the final tree `newNode` which is generated (the string source code generated by simply calling `newNode.ToString()`), I see that my directive has been added like this:

```
usingMyNamespace.SubNamespace;
```

I can see the same thing if I just do: `usingDirective.ToString()`. It seems very wrong, a space is needed and that should trigger a syntax error. What is going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to fix the problem:

```
SyntaxFactory.UsingDirective(
    SyntaxFactory.ParseName("MyNamespace.SubNamespace")).NormalizeWhitespace();
```

Comment: Thanks man! So it this whitespace thing just a visual trivia, so it does not really change anything (not harmful for both parsing and semantic analysis) or it is making any demage?

Comment: The syntax tree of Roslyn is not abstract, but concrete, that means that everything of source code is included in the three (so whitespace, comments, xml doc, everything). This is to make it possible to turn the three back into the original three. In your case, the three generated is not really valid, and needs the appropriate whitespace (though, I expect it to generate valid IL), which does NormalizeWhitespace. Alternatively, you can add WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation), if this is in a CodeFix, to indicate that the resulting node requires appropriate whitespace formatting.

Comment: Like a found out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40578806/what-is-the-canonical-way-to-convert-a-methoddeclarationsyntax-to-a-constructord ;) On the wiki of Roslyn, you can find more on nodes, tokes, and trivia (this topic): https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Roslyn%20Overview#syntax-trivia