# How do I insert a statement into a block with normalized whitespace using Roslyn?

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

I'm new to Roslyn. I'm writing a code fix provider that transforms `foreach` blocks that iterate through the results of a `Select`, e.g.

```
foreach (var item in new int[0].Select(i => i.ToString()))
{
    ...
}
```

to

```
foreach (int i in new int[0])
{
    var item = i.ToString();
    ...
}
```

To do this, I need to insert a statement at the beginning of the `BlockSyntax` inside the `ForEachStatementSyntax` that represents the `foreach` block. Here is my code for that:

```
var blockStatement = forEach.Statement as BlockSyntax;
if (blockStatement == null)
{
    return document;
}
forEach = forEach.WithStatement(
    blockStatment.WithStatements(
        blockStatement.Statements.Insert(0, selectorStatement));
```

Unfortunately, doing that results in the whitespace being off:

```
            foreach (int i in new int[0])
            {
var item = i.ToString();
                ...
            }
```

I Googled solutions for this. I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19712450/4077294), which recommended using either `Formatter.Format` or `SyntaxNode.NormalizeWhitespace`.

- I can't use `Formatter.Format` because that takes a `Workspace` parameter, and it looks I don't have access to a `Workspace` per [Roslyn: Current Workspace in Diagnostic with code fix project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23203206/4077294).
- I tried using `NormalizeWhitespace()` on the syntax root of the document, but that invasively formatted other code not related to the fix. I tried using it on just the `ForEachStatementSyntax` associated with the `foreach` block, and then calling `syntaxRoot = syntaxRoot.ReplaceNode(oldForEach, newForEach)`, but that results in the entire `foreach` block *not* being properly indented.

  ```
  namespace ConsoleApp1
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {
              var array = new int[0];
              int length = array.Length;

  foreach (int i in array)
  {
      string item = i.ToString();
  }        }
      }
  }
  ```

So is it possible to simply insert the statement with the correct indentation in the first place, without having to format other code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the [Formatter Annotation](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/Formatter.cs,24) to the nodes that you want the formatter to run on using [WithAdditionalAnnotations](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Syntax/SyntaxNodeOrToken.cs,7299021501f79de2)

`blockStatement.Statements.Insert(0, selectorStatement.WithAdditionalAnnotations(Formatter.Annotation))`

Comment: Thanks so much! Worked like a charm. Out of curiosity, do you know *why* adding that annotation causes the statement to be formatted? When I look at the [Roslyn source code](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/Formatter.cs,24) I see it's initialized as just a plain `new SyntaxAnnotation()`.

Comment: SyntaxAnnotation increments a global id when created so that `Formatter.Annotation == someAnnotation ` will only be true if `someAnnotation` is actually a reference to the same instance.